# Pressure in/on someone's chest

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

> Just the thought of going to work makes me feel pressure in/on my chest.

Should it be *in* or *on* here? Initially, I chose *on* because I think the pressure is pushing down *on* your chest. But a native English speaker told me *in* was the correct choice.

Comment: I guess 'on' would mean someone other than you pressuring you. 'in' would mean you feeling the pressure on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emotions such as anxiety, excitement, fear, passion, etc, can cause physical sensations due to action of muscles, the nervous system, breathing, and so on. We feel these sensations **in** our bodies. The regions affected can be the chest, abdomen, neck, among others. I myself have often felt a tightness in my chest at certain moments in my life, not all of them bad. A couple of years ago my doctor found that I had probably been suffering from asthma most of my life, and this would have increased this natural feeling.

[Anxiety chest pain](https://www.healthline.com/health/anxiety/anxiety-chest-pain)

Comment: This is a good general rule. However, things get more complex for "itch on my skin" vs "itch in my skin". Simple Google search suggests that the common usage favors latter 1:4. I would say both are perfectly understandable and that's what should count the most.